# My Java code is getting TimeLimit exceeded whereas the same logic in C/C++/Python/Python3 are getting accepted for larger testcases

Tags: java, python, c

Constraints:

```
0<T<100
0<N<10000
```

Input:

```
2
6
abcdef 
3 
abc
```

Output:

```
bdfeca 
bca
```

I tried to get this Problem fixed so much time and fed up with the wrong that I was getting,

I know C, C++ are faster, as they use only Compiler, compared to Java, Python, as they use Interpreter also,

But my code is getting finely done for Python2 and Python3,

Is their any other Logic that decrease the Time Complexity than this,

I think I have done it in O(n), Time Complexity.

My code in Java:(Where my code is getting Time Limit exceeded)

```
import java.util.*;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()), i;
        while ( t --> 0 )
        {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            String a = sc.nextLine();
            for(i=1;i<n;i+=2)
                System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
            i=n-1;
            if(n%2==0)
                i--;
            for(;i>=0;i-=2)
                System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

My code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t, n, i;
    char a[10000];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d %s",&n,a);
        for(i=1;i<n;i+=2)
            printf("%c",a[i]);
        i=n-1;
        if(!(n&1))
            i--;
        for(;i>=0;i-=2)
            printf("%c",a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code in Python3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    n=int(input())
    a=input()
    for i in range(1,n,2):
        print(a[i],end='')
    i=n-1
    if(n%2==0):
        i=i-1
    for q in range(i,-1,-2):
        print(a[q],end='')
    print("\n")
```

Limits:
`Time Limit: 0.15 sec(s) for each input file.
Memory Limit: 256 MB
Source Limit: 1024 KB`

Comment: Why this `while(t-->0)`? Don't you see how ugly that looks? Use more whitespace, specially around operators and after kewords. `if(` is nicer `if (` and `-->` is really bad. There is even a question here that calls it the *goes to* operator!!!

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Disagree. `while(t-->0)` clearly states the logic: `t` goes to `0`. I personally would prefer something like `while (t --> 0)`, but this obviously has better readability than `while (t-- > 0)`

Comment: Ok@Iharob Al Asimi

Comment: Since you have to print all the characters of the input, O(n) complexity is surely unbeatable. Maybe it is those `System.out.print(a.charAt(i));` that are slowing down in Java. You may try to accelerate it if you compose your output string and print it at once?

Comment: What is the time limit, exactly?  Java benchmarking is complicated, not least because of the time needed to load fundamental classes on startup.

Comment: @A.S.H Ok, I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the mistake where my Java code is getting slowed down,

i.e., at `System.out.println(a.charAt(i))`,

So to minimize it we use StringBuilders and update it and then finally print at final

By this we can say that `public char charAt(int index)` method takes some what more time compared to `public String substring(int beginIndex, int endingIndex)`(one of the Constructors)

So, My final Java Code Satisfying all conditions(with less time compared to before) is:

```
import java.util.*;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()), i;
        while(t-->0)
        {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");
            String a = sc.nextLine();
            for(i=1;i<n;i+=2)
                str.append(a.substring(i,i+1));
            i=n-1;
            if(n%2==0)
                i--;
            for(;i>=0;i-=2)
                str.append(a.substring(i,i+1));
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```